# How to make Indent output JSONs by annotations in RestController?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I need to pretty output JSONs. Is there an annotation for RestController that will help to do this? This is a spring boot application that produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE in @RequestMapping.

I found one way with the configuration in application.yml

```
jackson:
  serialization:
    indent-output: true
```

However, this solution imposes this rule on the entire project, and I want to do this for only one class.
Also, I think @JsonSerialize can help me, but I couldn't set up an annotation for pretty print

Comment: Does this annotation is effective on method/class level? `@JsonFormat(prettyPrint = true)`

Comment: @PAX JsonFormat has not property prettyPrint

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a simple `Person` class with 2 properties, `name` and `age`:

```
public class Person {

   private String name;
   private int age;

   public Person(String name, int age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public int getAge() {
       return age;
   }
}
```

And let's say you have a spring `RestController` that returns a `Person` object as JSON:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

   @GetMapping("/person")
   public Person getPerson() {
      return new Person("John Doe", 30);
   }
}
```

By default, the JSON output will be compact and not indented:

```
{"name":"John Doe","age":30}
```

To pretty-print the JSON output, you can use the `@JsonFormat` annotation on the `Person` class:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public class Person {
    //...
}
```

The `shape` property of the annotation specifics the shape of the serialized JSON. In this case, we set it to `JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT` to indicate that the output should be formatted as a JSON object.

Now, when you call the `/Person` endpoint, the JSON output will be pretty-printed

```
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "age" : 30
}
```

As you can see, the JSON output is now indented and easier to read.

Comment: Its doesn't work. I tried JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT) on entity, on controller class and on methods in controller.